# Store - accessing sale meta information in template

Tags: expresso-store

Is there a way of accessing other sale information (other than the sale_price) in the template? I'd like to be able to display the sale name that the discount relates to...!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a version of Store greater then 2.1 you would be able to use the `{adjustments}` tag pair to loop through all discounts and adjustments to your order. Something along the lines of:

```
{adjustments}
    <tr>
        <td>{adjustment:name}</td>
        <td>{adjustment:amount}</td>
    </tr>
{/adjustments}
```

You can see all of the available tags within the adjustments loop [here](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#adjustments_loop) in the docs.

Comment: I think this only applies to the checkout tag though; if I want to show a different price and attribute it to a particular sale witihin the exp:store:product tag I don't think I can access the adjustments tag. This is really infuriating, I just want a way to offer different prices to members and state this wherever I want to promote it. "Full price 6.99 / Member price 5.99" - that kind of thing. I get the feeling I should have stuck with Cartthrob.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be able to solve this with product modifieres:

```
{modifier_options}
    <option value="{option_id}">
       {option_name}
       {if price_mod_inc_tax_val} ({price_mod_inc_tax}) {/if}
    </option>
{/modifier_options}
```

`option_name` could be Member price, you'd have to make the modifier price `-1.00` for the calculation to be correct.

You could also check the [sale tag](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#if_on_sale). You can limit a sale to member group so that seems like something that would be useful for your use case.

Comment: I've tried the sale tag and it would be perfect if I could access the sale name - that way I could set up a sale called 'member price' and make it available to members. Actually even that's not perfect because non-logged in users won't see it. I'll try the modifiers! Thanks Jannermans.

Comment: Hmm - I can display the modifier correctly, so that's good. But how do I make it only actually available to a logged-in member? I want to display it to everyone but only give the member the benefit. And it can't be a selectable option, it has to be the only option - you either pay full price or the member price. Tricky, or easy? (Thinking ahead as well, what happens if I have more modifiers that have nothing to do with membership?).

Comment: That's why the sales option is probably better, since that already takes care of all the member checks for you. It's not in the docs but have you tried sale_id, sale_title, etc?

Comment: {sale_id}, {sale_title}, {sale_name} - none of these get parsed and just output as they are, so I guess they're not in the docs because they're not intended to work!